# ImportError: Couldn't import Django in running Docker image

Tags: django, docker

I am so new in Docker and I have dockerized a simple django application and this is Dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /app
COPY  . .
RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt 
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD ["python3","manage.py", "runserver","0.0.0.0:8000
```

and this docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.9"
   
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - d
```

and this is the packages in requirements.txt :

```
asgiref==3.4.1
Django==3.2.9
pytz==2021.3
sqlparse==0.4.2
```

i have created image myapp 4 successfuly and when i tried to run this image with dcoker run myapp4 i got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 13, in main
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: did you inspect the generated requirements.txt? does it include Django?

Comment: I updated the question you can see the packages in requirements.txt

Comment: Looks all right, maybe post the logs of the Docker build, something wrong during the install of the Python dependencies?

Comment: The `RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt` line overwrites the package list from your source tree with a listing of what's installed in the default Python Docker image.  Does deleting this line help?